# Object JavaScript из двух массивов разной длины

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива разной длины:

```
const keys = ['744128789503859', '546133235926688', '5461332359254778'];
const values = ['073', '611'];
```

Хочу из этих масивов создать `Object` такого вида:

```
{744128789503859:073, 546133235926688:611, 5461332359254778:073}
```

то есть, чтобы значения `values` присваивались по кругу для `keys`

У меня получилось сделать это только при одинаковой длине массивов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы закольцевать индекс для меньшего массива, нужно взять остаток от деления индекса большего на длину меньшего:

```js
const keys = ['744128789503859', '546133235926688', '5461332359254778'];
const values = ['073', '611'];

console.log(keys.reduce((acc, cur, i) => ({ ...acc,
  [cur]: values[i % values.length]
}), {}))
```

Comment: Превосходно! Благодарю!

Comment: `...acc` - брррррр